# Implementation of Half Sync Half Asyncc pattern of POSA in Android Asynctask

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-asynctask

Please refer to the following piece of code which has been taken from the Asynctask of Android. i think its an an example of Half Sync Half Async pattern of the concurrent patterns from the Pattern Oriented Software Architecture book. Can someone please confirm?

```
private static class SerialExecutor implements Executor {    
    final ArrayDeque<Runnable> mTasks = new ArrayDeque<Runnable>();        
    Runnable mActive;        

    public synchronized void execute(final Runnable r) {        
        mTasks.offer(new Runnable() {        
            public void run() {        
                try {        
                    r.run();        
                } finally {        
                    scheduleNext();
                }        
            }
        });

        if (mActive == null) {        
            scheduleNext();
        }        
    }        

    protected synchronized void scheduleNext() {        
        if ((mActive = mTasks.poll()) != null) {        
            THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.execute(mActive);        
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I have got the whole idea. Of course the SerialExecutor is an example of Half Sync - Half Async pattern. Here goes my write-up for the Asynctask internals...   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_zihWXAwgTAdJc013-bOLUHPMrjeUBZnDuPkzMxEEj0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

So yes, I can confirm that this is true.

Also, I personally discussed this with one of the POSA2 authors Doug Schmidt (My PhD Adviser), just to be 100% sure(and give you more confidence). He gave me a link to video in which he discusses the topic in depth.

This is from a course He teaches at Vanderbilt University in which he covers advanced operating principles (such as concurrency), which uses Android as the example OS/Platform.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZ29DAcmcLE

Also, This topic has been covered in the past, and will be covered again in the reoccurring  POSA course on Coursera. That also discusses Software Patterns and shows them in the Android Framework.

https://www.coursera.org/course/posa

Comment: Thank you for confirming it. I like Doug's lectures at Coursera. These are really very informative.. I would also like to take this opportunity to thank Doug and Coursera for enlightening many eager learners like me across the globe...